# How can I change the name of the object in this case?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, calendar

I want to make my own calendar with C#.
Because of that i want to create as much panels as the month has days.

I tried to do it with a for loop, but it doesn't work.
I think the problem is, that the name of the object never changes.

But how can I change the name of the object every time it loops through?

```
public void createPanel()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1 || DateTime.Now.Month == 3 || DateTime.Now.Month == 5 || DateTime.Now.Month == 7 || DateTime.Now.Month == 8 || DateTime.Now.Month == 10 || DateTime.Now.Month == 12)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i == 31; i++)
        {
            int locationX = 12;
            int locationY = 74;
            //Create Panel
            Panel test = new Panel();
            //Fill Panel
            test.Name = "panel" + i;
            test.Width = 200;
            test.Height = 100;
            test.BackColor = Color.White;
            test.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(locationX, locationY);
            this.Controls.Add(test);
            test.Show();
            if(i == 7 || i == 14 || i == 21)
            {
                locationY += 106;
                locationX = 12;
            }
            locationX += 206;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". Do you get a compile time error, a runtime error, or do you only get the last created object ?

Comment: What exception does it give?

Comment: The name of what object?

Comment: No, it doesn't work because it overwrites my panel every time. I tough it's because of the name...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I mean the name of the windows form "panel".

Comment: We will need the code of the whole thing instead the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i == 31; i++)
```

is wrong. You will never reach the inside of the for loop, since i is equal to 0 and expected to be 31.

Maybe you meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
```

I'm assuming there's lots of other issues with your code, but fix this first and maybe open new and more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the months in your if statement, you might want to use this instead:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

So your loop should look something like:

```
var numDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
for (int i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
{
   // your code here
}
```

You can get the selected year and month from DateTime.Today, or just let the user select it for themselves.